# Getting no search results

Tags: python, django, search, solr, django-haystack

I just installed and setup haystack and solr with django 1.3, but when I search (with haystack default template), I get nothing.  I copy and pasted the solr schema and updated my indexes, but I am getting no results.  Maybe my model/table isn't connected to solr?  How do I fix this?  I have no idea what's going on...

Thanks a bunch!

added info:

schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<schema name="default" version="1.1">
  <types>
<fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<!-- Numeric field types that manipulate the value into
     a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form,
     but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering,
     so that range queries work correctly. -->
<fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>

   <fields>   
    <!-- general -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
    <field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

    <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="sint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="slong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="sfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="sdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>


    <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

  </fields>

  <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />
</schema>
```

search_indexes:

```
class PostIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=False)

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Post.objects.all()


site.register(Post, PostIndex)
```

search_config:

```
import haystack

haystack.autodiscover()
```

settings:

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'site.search_config'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'solr'
HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post more information like your search indexes?

Comment: added new info, do you need anything else?

Comment: @Derek What version of Solr did you install? Haystack is saying 1.3+ , does that include the latest Solr 3.3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to populate the field `text` in your search index somehow; either map it to model field - or - [use a template for this](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html#handling-data)! For the start you should be fine using a template, therefore set `use_template=True` and add a template. Read [this paragraph](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html#handling-data) for more information on how to create the template file!

Comment: cool thx, can u explain to me why u need this? also i notice that you always need to select with model to search, how do you search all models or a certain few models without using the checkbox? And do you update index every time you change search_indexes or some time else?